# How to apply Vue.set to an array of objects for adding a property to each element?

Tags: vuejs2

I have an array of objects that is fetched from a remote data API. I need to add a new property to each object so I can make it reactive in my UI. I see that in the VueJS2 docs, there are some known ["change detection caveats"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) and reactivity limitations.

Thus, doing this does not work in my app:

```
computed: {

...mapState(['countryChanges']),
```

}

```
methods: {
        newCountryChangesArray() {
          // create new country changes array and add a 'status' property for each
          let newCountryArrWithStatusField = this.countryChanges
          newCountryArrWithStatusField.forEach(el => {
            el.status = 0
          })
          return newCountryArrWithStatusField
        }
    
    }
```

and then in my template I tried but the changes are not reactive

`v-for="country in newCountryChangesArray"`

OK, i see there is a known limitation and the VueJS docs state to use `Vue.set` or `this.$set` to add reactive properties to existing data. But, how would I do it to an array of Objects?

Comment: When is `newCountryChangesArray()` method executed? Could you add it into your script?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, define a variable `newCountryArrWithStatusField` in `data()`:

```
data() {
   return {
      newCountryArrWithStatusField: [],
   }    
}
```

Then, change `newCountryChangesArray()` method like:

```
newCountryChangesArray() {
   // create new country changes array and add a 'status' property for each
   this.newCountryArrWithStatusField = this.countryChanges
   this.newCountryArrWithStatusField.forEach(el => {
      el.status = 0
   })
   this.newCountryArrWithStatusField = [].concat(this.newCountryArrWithStatusField)
}
```

Finally, change `v-for` as: `v-for="country in newCountryArrWithStatusField"`

`[].concat(this.newCountryArrWithStatusField)` is the key of reactivity here.

Comment: Thx you I will study and get back to you!